# Wicket AjaxIndicatorAppender across panels

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have 2 panels on one page and in first panel I call Ajax link and do some back end operations with long duration. In another panel I want show `AjaxIndicatorAppender`.

If I use `AjaxIndicatorAppender` with listener in the first panel, everything work fine, but if I use it in panel 2, it does nothing. Any help how call Ajax in panel 1 and show the Ajax indicator in panel 2? I am lost.

In panel1 (menu panel):

```
modal1.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            some code.....

            send(getPage(), Broadcast.DEPTH, new ContentUpdate(target));


            etc...
```

in panel2 (content panel)

```
@Override
public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
super.onEvent(event);
if (event.getPayload() instanceof ContentUpdate) {
    AjaxRequestTarget target = ((ContentUpdate)event.getPayload()).getTarget();

            ContentSection section = new ContentSection("content0",contentView.getCustomSectionList().get(0));
            listItems.get("content0").replaceWith(section);
            listItems.get("pagingNavigator0").replaceWith(new PagingNavigator("pagingNavigator0", section.getDataView()));
            target.add(wmc);
}
}
```

How can I trigger listener in panel 2?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem. My parent page can trigger IAjaxIndicatorAware too. I move this interface to my parent page and I call IndicatorMarkupId from the second panel.

Thank for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `AjaxLink` should implement `IAjaxIndicatorAware` interface and `#getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId()` should return the markup id of the HTML element with the loading indicator in Panel2.

But this way you would couple Panel1 with Panel2. Since you use Wicket Event mechanism I guess you try to keep them decoupled.
Probably you need to show a page-wide loading indicator instead.